# How to have access inside div element?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

i am trying to create simple Rock,paper, scissor game, 
 but i have some case, i want to have access on div which id is firstplayer, also this div has increment function, which increases value by 1... if in form field i choose 12, an when i press "firstplayer" and it value will increase to 12, i want to console.log("you win"), i tried  a lot, but it's not works, what can i do, to solve this problem?

```
<!-----my html---->
<form action="#">
        <label for="numbers">Game up to:</label>
        <select id="form" >
          <option value="7" >7</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
          <option value="15">15</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" id="submit">
      </form>
<div>
              <h4 onclick="increment()">Firstplayer</h4>
            <div id="firstplayer">

            </div>
          </div>

///my js
const firsPlayer = document.getElementById("firstplayer");
const Form = document.getElementById("submit");

form.addEventListener("input", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.target.value==="12"){ 
   return playerwin()
  }
})

var x=0;
function increment(){
   return firsPlayer.innerHTML = ++x;
}

// i tried this but it's not working
function playerwin(){   
         if(firsPlayer.childNodes[0].nodeValue == 12){
            console.log("you win")
         }
}
```

my code here https://codepen.io/kafka2001/pen/LYpmexe

Comment: When you click on the title, it calls your `increment` function, but this function does not call `playerwin`. Try to think about the logic of your code. Stackoverflow is here to answer question about a specific problem, not to give advice about how to learn the logic of programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what the final result should be but please check the code below that illustrates how it could basically work. Just adapt it to your needs to obtain the desired result.

```js
const firsPlayer = document.getElementById("firstplayer");
const select = document.getElementById("select");
var x = 0;

function increment() {
  firsPlayer.innerHTML = Number(firsPlayer.innerHTML) + 1;
}

function addSelected() {
  firsPlayer.innerHTML = Number(firsPlayer.innerHTML) + Number(select.value);
}

function playerwin() {
  if (firsPlayer.childNodes[0].nodeValue == 12) {
    console.log("you win")
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onClick="increment();" value="Increment">
<div>
  <h4 onclick="addSelected()">Firstplayer</h4>
  <div id="firstplayer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You get wrong end of the stick,  i don't want to increase firstplayer value by value which was chosen from form, i  have increased  number by one,  but when firstpalyer number value reaches the mark that was marked in form, i want to conole log("you win"). for example i chose 7 in form field, and when firstplayer number value will reach to 7, i want to conole.log("you win").